# Как установить CMS?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

Если кто знаком с Unlabeled CMS, расскажите поподробней, как ее установить???

Имеется установка в [картинках](http://code.google.com/p/unlabeled/).Но я не могу понять 2 пункт.2.В качестве корневой директории сайта необходимо прописать путь к папке "public"Как это сделать на localhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дописать в файле конфигурации виртуальных хостов сервера папку "/public", типа:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>  DocumentRoot "Z:/home/localhost/www/public"  ...
```